# Email para promocionar el nuevo código de conducta

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, traducciones

**Update:** El mail está traducido y listo para enviar (el texto y el screenshot en esta pregunta es la versión final). El equipo de CMs está al tanto.

---

Desde ayer tenemos nuestro nuevo [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) en español (gracias a los que ayudaron en la traducción! y quienes vean cosas para mejorar... adelante!).

Parte del release, es mandar un mail a todos los usuarios que sólo pertenecen a Stack Overflow en español pero no tienen cuenta en otros sitios (ya que los usuarios con cuentas en otros sitios recibieron/van a recibir el mail en inglés).

Nuevamente, gracias a la ayuda de nuestro equipo de traducción anónimo (o no tan anónimo) lo tradujimos entre todos.

Sin embargo, como una vez que mandemos el mail medio que no podemos volver atrás (a diferencia de las páginas del sitio, donde podemos ir refinando las traducciones para que eventualmente queden hermosas), es que queremos recibir feedback sobre la traducción del mail antes de mandarlo.

### Mail original

[Podés ver un screenshot acá](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7T4T.png)

#### Asunto

Our new Code of Conduct is here

#### Contenido

> Join us in building a kind, collaborative community
>
> Read Code of Conduct
>
> Our new Code of Conduct came from numerous conversations with the Stack Exchange community. Together, you helped create a code that reinforces our commitment to mutual respect and kindness. Take a moment to read our newly updated Code of Conduct.
>
> Here are some highlights:
>
> - If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Follow our guidelines and remember that our community is made possible by volunteers.
> - If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.
> - Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and be open when receiving it. Edits, comments, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community.
> - Be kind and avoid sarcasm - tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop participating and move on.
> - Flag harmful behavior, whether it’s directed at you or others. It’ll notify moderators or automatically delete the post.
>
> Read the full Code of Conduct
>
> Thanks for helping us be better.

### Versión traducida: (Actualizada el 20 de Agosto a las 15:55 UTC)

[Podés ver un screenshot acá](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScRX5.png)

#### Asunto

Conoce nuestro nuevo Código de conducta

#### Contenido

> Ayúdanos a construir una comunidad amable y colaborativa
>
> Lee el Código de conducta
>
> Nuestro nuevo código de conducta es el resultado del trabajo conjunto con la comunidad de Stack Exchange. Juntos, hemos creado un código que refuerza nuestro compromiso de respeto mutuo y amabilidad. Tómate un momento para leer nuestro nuevo código de conducta recién actualizado.
>
> Aquí hay algunos puntos destacados:
>
> **Si estás aquí para obtener ayuda, haz que sea lo más fácil posible ayudarte**. Sigue nuestras pautas y recuerda que nuestra comunidad es posible gracias a los voluntarios.​
>
> **Si estás aquí para ayudar a los demás, sé paciente y hospitalario.** Ofrece apoyo si ves a alguien que tiene dificultades o que necesita ayuda.
>
> **Sé claro y constructivo cuando brindes comentarios, y abierto al recibirlos.** Las ediciones, comentarios y sugerencias son partes saludables de nuestra comunidad.
>
> **Sé amable y evita el sarcasmo - el tono es difícil de descifrar en línea.** Si en una situación se te dificulta actuar con amabilidad, deja de participar y sigue adelante.
>
> **Reporta el comportamiento dañino, ya sea dirigido a ti o a otros.** Esto notificará a los moderadores o eliminará automáticamente la publicación.
>
> Lee el Código de conducta
>
> Gracias por ayudarnos a ser mejores.

Comment: El pedido en MSE fue por aca https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313873/141717.

Comment: ¿Se puede modificar la firma? Sale un nombre de un empleado que es Vice President bla bla. Propongo sustituirlo por _tus amigos de SOes_ :P

Comment: @fedorqui no, no se puede modificar

Comment: +1 esta version me gusta!

Comment: ¡Buen trabajo, gente! Gracias @g3rv4 por gestionarlo tan bien.

Comment: ¡Muy buen trabajo! Vamos entonces a poner esto en vivo. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Sé claro y constructivo cuando brindes comentarios, y sé abierto al recibirlos.

Creo que la la "`,`" no se debe poner antes de la "`y`" 
, ademas creo que puede quedar mejor asi:

> Sé claro y constructivo cuando brindes comentarios, como también,
>   atento a recibir.